# Passing common data into the _Layout.cshtml in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In an ASP.Net MVC Application, I'm trying to generate a top navigation bar from the database table. I follow the Database first approach. using EntityFramework

My scenario as follows :

I have 3 tables `MainMenu`, `SubMenu` and `ItemMenu`. The `ItemMenu` table knows it's MainMenu and the SubMenu. According to those details, the top menu bar should be rendered on the _Layout.cshtml page.

How to implement this..? Should I create a partial view for MenuBar or is there any other easy ways to accomplish this?

Comment: This question is too broad: "please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."

Comment: you can use Partial View or Html.Action for this case

Answer (score 2):

You can try  Foreach loop to show main menu ,sub menu and child menu.

You can try very similar like bellow

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @foreach(var item in mainMenu)
    {
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@item.MainMenu1<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    @foreach(var subItem in item.SubMenu){
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@subItem.SubMenu1<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                @foreach(var childItem in subItem.ChildMenu){
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(@childItem, "Action", "Controller")</li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </li> 
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>    
    }

</ul>
```

You can fix design as yourself.
Note: Get data from action as list of data using multiple object

Comment: Thank you very much @tebbe93 for your reply. Kindly tell me how to pass that `item` from a controller to `_Layout.cshtml` which controller should I use? If we need to render a specific page, We can pass a model data or ViewBag or something from the specific controller method to the corresponding view. But in `_Layout.cshtml` how to do it? my purpose of doing this is, generating menu according to the user privileges.

Comment: You can take partial action to your home controller and generate a view.Inside view take a section .After completing menu design render section to your  layout  page or home index  page. Depending on menu how do you want to use